# How can you restrict user to only input alphabets in Python?

Tags: python, loops, break, restrict, isalpha

I am a beginner trying to learn Python. First question.

Trying to find a way to ask users to input alphabets only.
Wrote this but it doesn't work!
It returns `True` and then skips the rest before continuing to the `else` clause.
`break` doesn't work either.

Can someone point out why?
I assume it's very elementary, but I'm stuck and would appreciate it if someone could pull me out.

```
while True:
    n = input("write something")
    if print(n.isalpha()) == True:
        print(n)
        break
    else:
        print("Has to be in alphabets only.")
```

Comment: `if n.isalpha() is True:` (or just `if n.isalpha():`) . you check the return value of `print` which is `None`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the bug, below is the updated code:

```
while True:
    n = input("write something: ")
    if n.isalpha() == True:
        print(n)
        break
    else:
        print("Has to be in alphabets only.")
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been struggling on this for hours. So Happy!

Comment: This can be optimized by dropping the `== True` part. The if condition can be written as `if n.isalpha():`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is the `print` function.  `print` does not return anything, so your `if` statement is always comparing `None` to `True`.

```
while True:
    n = input("write something")
    if n.isalpha():
        print(n)
        break
    else:
        print("Has to be in alphabets only.")
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't expect such help in so short a time! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement should be `if n.isalpha() == True:`. `print` won't return anything and so the value is `None`. Then, you are comparing `None` with `True`

```
while True:
    n = input("write something")
    if n.isalpha() == True:
        print(n)
        break
    else:
        print("Has to be in alphabets only.")
```

Comment: Wow! so swift and great! It works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Most Welcome @Zane

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `print(n.isaplha())`, it will be always True. Remove print() and use only **`n.isalpha()`

Try this:-**

```
while True:
    n = input("write something")
    if print(n.isalpha()) == True:
        print(n)
        break
    else:
        print("Has to be in alphabets only.")
```

Comment: `print` returns `None` (as most of the other answers point out). it will not *always be True* (what does that even mean?).

Comment: It won't return none. Try it: `a = 'Hi'` `print(a.isalpha())`, doesn't it return true? And sorry if I am still wrong

Comment: what i mean is this: `a = print("something")`, then `a is None`. what you are printing in your example is the return value of `isalpha` (which is a `bool` indeed).

Comment: Ok understood and sorry!

Comment: Thank you! I am so emancipated now... After hours of scratching my head! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks everybody! Blown away by some much enthusiasm in helping out a hapless newbie! Scared to post first question, but happy to have done it! Again extreme appreciation!

Comment: How is this code fifferent from the code in the question?